# cannot get angular ui bootstrap modal to work

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular-ui with bootstrap and when I try to use the modal, it brings up something and darkens the background, but does not display my content. I see it requesting the proper background and window files. If I use Chrome tools to troubleshoot, I only see this inside the content:

```
<div class="modal-content" modal-transclude=""></div>
```

Should I see the transcluded HTML inside this? If I edit it manually within Chrome tools, and then enter in some text, it displays properly.

All other aspects of the modal seem to work; clicking outside kills the dialog, and it accepts the 'sm' and 'lg' size parameters.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

I'm using:

- angular 1.2.21
- ui-bootstrap-0.11.0
- //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Maybe there is an incompatibility with these three?